# Convert pdf to pdfx maintaining vector graphics / without rasterisation (e.g. using ghostscript)

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, vector-graphics

I would like to save a pdf to a pdf/x.
The pdf contains a vector graphic.
When I convert it using ghostscript v9.53.3 on windows 10 and using...

```
gswin64c -dPDFX -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK -sOutputFile=document-pdfx.pdf document.pdf
```

...graphics and text are rasterized.

What can I do to prevent this?

If I do the same using Adobe Acrobat DC Pro my graphics remain as vector graphics.

I could not really find something helpfull at https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/VectorDevices.htm

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the file contains (or claims to contain) PDF transparency operations. If that is the case, and the transparency *actually* has no visual effect (which is not uncommon), you could try adding -dNOTRANSPARENCY to the command line.

Comment: Cool. Just be aware that if there is "real" transparency, that will prevent it from displaying correctly.